# Flutter: modal_bottom_sheet (iOS style)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, modal-dialog

How can I animate the modal_bottom_sheet (https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) like it does **after** pushing with `MaterialWithModalsPageRoute`. I start my app and want to show this modal on the first page on button pressed, but it doesn't animate like it should.

Answer (score 0):

this fixes it: https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/159

My mistake was, that i added `onGenerateRoute` **and** `home` to my `MaterialApp`

Here's the code that's working from the issue above:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialWithModalsPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text("Press"),
          onPressed: () {
            showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              expand: true,
              builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Hello"),
    );
  }
}
```